# ¿Como solucionar lectura de ".(punto)" como ",(coma)" en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Les comento, Tengo un sistema elaborado en **Visual Studio**  con **C#** que conecta a **SQL Server** desde 8 computadoras diferentes al mismo tiempo. El problema es que en 2 Computadoras de las 8 me Arroja entre algunos otros el siguiente Error cuanto agrego un nuevo cliente:
(Antes funcionaba correctamente en las 8 PC).

```
**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**
```

La inserción la hago de esta manera:
(Cabe destacar que **CAMPOPNeta.text** y **CAMPOPTotal.text** los tenia sin convertirlos en Double, los convertí para ver si eso solucionaba el problema).

```
String InsertarDatosSeguro2 = "INSERT INTO DATOSSEGURO2 ";
InsertarDatosSeguro2 += "VALUES('" + CBCPromotor.Text + "','" + poliza.Text + "'," +Convert.ToDouble(CAMPOPNeta.Text)+ "," + Convert.ToDouble(CAMPOPTotal.Text) + "," + CAMPOPDescuento.Text + ",'"+TipoPago.Text+"')";
SqlCommand comando4 = new SqlCommand();
comando4.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
comando4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comando4.CommandText = InsertarDatosSeguro2;
try
{
   comando4.ExecuteNonQuery();
   comando4.Dispose();
   comando4 = null;
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("ERROR INSERT INTO DATOSSEGURO2: " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Localice el error en esta tabla, por lo que veo no es error de sintaxis ni que tenga datos de mas.

[image: aqui se muestra la tabla con las columnas ya insertadas]

Siguiendo con mi investigación para la solución del problema y con ayuda de SQL ---> TOOLS -> **SQL Server Profiler** me doy cuenta que en las dos computadoras los puntos me los lee como ,(comas)

[image: inserción en la computadora mala]

Ahora bien... insertando un nuevo cliente en una de las 6 computadoras de las que no marca error se muestra de esta manera:

[image: Inserción en la computadora buena]

Espero vean clara la diferencia, la pregunta es... el Error esta en **SQL Server**? o esta en el sistema Elaborado en **Visual Studio**?.

Espero y puedan ayudare en la búsqueda de la Solución a mi Problema, de ante mano Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Eh, tiene pinta de líos en la configuración regional al enviar los datos (usa el separador de miles y de decimales que le da el sistema y pues... yo los predefiniría para la app independiente de la terminal)

Comment: el error esta en la configuracion regional de la pc... pero, para evitar todo esto, si usas consultas parametrizadas en lugar de armar el query a mano, se soluciona sin que hagas mucho mas...

Comment: El detalle que así como pasa con esta inserción pasa con consultas y otras query's que traigan con sigo un dato double o numeric.

Comment: Como te dicen, es por la configuración regional. Compara la región de los 2 equipos que fallan con los 6 que funciona bien y verás que es diferente a los equipos que funciona bien.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a los 3, ahora no se como dar por concluida la Pregunta.

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, no deberías construir las consultas de esa forma... aparte de que está rogando por un SQL injection ese código.

Comment: Podríamos dejar que alfabravo y gbianchi lancen una moneda al aire y decidan cual de los dos va a escribir una respuesta para que la coloques como _la_ respuesta.

Comment: @eftshift0 Muchas gracias por tu comentario, Una vez acabando el sistema comenzare a cambiar el tipo de consulta. Lo hice de esa manera por que es la que sabia, pero agradezco el comentario para futuros proyectos y evolución de este.

Comment: Ya tenes que cambiar el modo de las consultas.. y no sabria como poner una respuesta a esta.. ya que lo que decimos son la sugerencia de como se soluciona mas que la respuesta.. demos la pregunta por cerrada por lo que gusten...

Comment: poliza.Text lo pasas como string y es int en la tabla. Lo correcto es que uses parametrización para evitar estos errores y problemas de tipos de datos. Por otro lado antes de enviar un double o fechas debes convertir el formateo a tipo de datos regional/cultura etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente, ya cheque las configuraciones de las PC y en efecto...eso era. @gbianchi y a Alfabravo

Comment: Poliza.text no es int es String, guarda 9 Dijitos los cuales NO los uso para hacer operaciones o algo... Como son solo de Lectura no me es indispensable guardarlo como int. Pero muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Ah y los montos no deben ser double... deben ser decimal por un problema de precision

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo correcto es que cambies la cultura de la APP pero esto afecta tanto fechas como números y no se como es la configuracion de la pc. Lo puntual en este caso es el decimal. Entonces en cada insert/update deberias de formatear para que el decimal sea un punto "." en vez de una ","
Ejemplo basico:

```
int poliza = Int32.Parse(poliza.Text);
        String campoNeta;
        String campoTotal;
        String campoDto;
        String tipoDePago = TipoPago.Text;

        String decimalChar = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
        if (!decimalChar.Equals('.'))
        {
            NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
            nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = '.';
            campoNeta = Double.Parse(CAMPOPNeta.Text.Trim).ToString(nfi);
            campoTotal = Double.Parse(CAMPOPTotal.Text.Trim).ToString(nfi);
            campoDto = Double.Parse(CAMPOPDescuento.Text.Trim).ToString(nfi);
        }
        else {
            campoNeta = CAMPOPNeta.Text.Trim;
            campoTotal = CAMPOPTotal.Text.Trim;
            campoDto = CAMPOPDescuento.Text.Trim;
        }

        String InsertarDatosSeguro2 = "INSERT INTO DATOSSEGURO2(ClavePromo, NumPoliza, PrimaNeta, PrimaTotal, PorcentajeDescuento, TipoPago)values(@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)";
       
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(MenuInicio.conexion);
        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBCPromotor.Text);

        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = poliza);
        //Si bien el tipo de tablas es decimal, enviamos en varchar por la posible conversión de formateo del numero.
        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = campoNeta);
        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = campoTotal);
        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = campoDto);
        comand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TipoPago.Text);
        comand.Prepare();
        comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: La idea empezó bien, pero sigue con el problema de que está abierto a inyección de sql. Hay que parametrizar la consulta.

Comment: Pense en agregar el uso de statment pero me concentre en el problema puntual de la app. Voy actualizar para que quede cubierto el tema del SQLInj. Gracias por recordar.

Comment: Excelente, ya solo es cuestión de cambiar el tipo varchar por un dato numérico y hasta podríamos evitarnos la validación.

Comment: Hola Luis. Lo pense pero cuando formateo con NumberFormatInfo por la diferencia de cultura de la app con el servidor no puedo pasarlo como double/numerico. Pero la parametrizacion de un double y un string es igual pasa con comillas.