# Problemas al insertar un registro con decimales a SQL server desde C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

estoy haciendo una aplicación en c# conectada a SQL server. con este metodo inserto mi registro a la base de datos

```
public static void insertar(int items, double valor, String formaDePago, String fecha)
        {
            comand.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
            comand.CommandText = "insert into Venta values ("+items+", "+valor+",'"+formaDePago+"', '"+fecha+"')";
            comand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

y esta es la sentencia que user para crear la tabla Venta

```
create table Venta
(   
Numero_Venta int identity(1,1) primary key,
Items int,
Valor decimal(19,3),
formaPago varchar(40),
fecha date
)
```

el problema es que cuando mando un valor decimal en el campo (Valor)  como 2.5, 3.5 etc.... me sale este error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Venta' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.'

Si mando un numero sin decimales, se inserta sin ningún problema.
¿A que se podría deber esto?

Comment: Es mejor que especifiques las columnas a afectar. EJM insert into Venta (Items, Valor, formaPago, fecha) values("+items+", "+valor+",'"+formaDePago+"', '"+fecha+"')

Comment: Ya lo había intentado y me sale este error, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.  Es como si al haber un decimal, el numero después del punto lo tomara como un numero deferente y lo interpretara como que estoy intentando insertar el numero_venta que es autoincremental. lo veo así porque como dije, si es un numero sin nada a la derecha, como "27.000" se inserta el registro normalmente.

Comment: Si son valores, deberias usar decimal en lugar de double. Deberias pasar los parametros como parametros, en una query parametrizada y no concatenarlos. Debes agregar si o si la lista de campos (si no, sql no sabe donde va cada valor). Proba todo eso, y tu problema se va a solucionar solo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: usa parametros, y solucionado

Comment: Tal cual, con parámetros si funciona. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Muy bien que solucionaste con parámetros, que es la forma correcta y segura de enviar los datos a como lo comenta @gbianchi. pero queda la duda y sería bueno identificar el origen del error cuando pasas los valores concatenados, pues probablemente uno que otro tendrá este mismo inconveniente.

Prueba con el método anterior y pasa el valor entre comillas simples, podría ser el formato, solo de esa manera es que podría salir el mensaje "The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

He tratado de replicar tu escenario con variables tipo tabla. además, agregue el posible error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ESto es una respuesta? las variables llevan siempre el punto como decimal.. seria raro que una variable numerica tuviera coma como separador decimal...

Comment: Eso depende si has configurado correctamente la región en la aplicación, de lo contrario la aplicación toma la región de la PC. Por ejemplo si tu configuración en la pc tienes región español españa, el separador de miles es un punto(.) y el de decimales una coma (,), o si me equivoco porfavor escríbeme. precisamente por eso publiqué mi respuesta, para ayudar y buscar solución al problema.

Comment: no. no confundas el separador que ves en pantalla, con como se guardan las variables internas de tu lenguaje. Las variables siempre separan los decimales con puntos....

Comment: No siempre los separan con comas estimado, eso depende de la región, comprobado en c# windows form y asp.net. Encontré un caso similar, leer : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380238/como-solucionar-lectura-de-punto-como-coma-en-sql-server

Comment: estamos hablando de cosas distintas.. vuelvo a preguntar.. esto es una respuesta? porque esto no responde a la pregunta....

Comment: Estimado, esta en todo su derecho a votar en contra. saludos

Comment: no es votar en contra. hay un reporte al respecto, y la seccion respuestas es para respuestas. Esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas...